# Вывод массива php в список в зависимости от ключа

Tags: php

Как вывести маркированный список из массива php в зависимости от ключей массива. Как вывести простой массив через foreach и забросить его в список понимаю, а вот с ключами вышла проблема

```
<?
$data = array(
array('ID'=>100, 'PARENT_ID' => 0, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1',),
array('ID'=>2, 'PARENT_ID' => 0, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 2',),
array('ID'=>3, 'PARENT_ID' => 0, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 3',),
array('ID'=>4, 'PARENT_ID' => 0, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 4',),
array('ID'=>52, 'PARENT_ID' => 100, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.1',),
array('ID'=>6, 'PARENT_ID' => 100, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.2',),
array('ID'=>7, 'PARENT_ID' => 100, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.3',),
array('ID'=>8, 'PARENT_ID' => 100, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.4',),
array('ID'=>9, 'PARENT_ID' => 52, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.1.1',),
array('ID'=>10, 'PARENT_ID' => 52, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.1.2',),
array('ID'=>11, 'PARENT_ID' => 52, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.1.3',),
array('ID'=>12, 'PARENT_ID' => 52, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.1.4',),
array('ID'=>13, 'PARENT_ID' => 9, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.1.1.1',),
array('ID'=>14, 'PARENT_ID' => 9, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.1.1.2',),
array('ID'=>15, 'PARENT_ID' => 9, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.1.1.3',),
array('ID'=>16, 'PARENT_ID' => 9, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 1.1.1.4',),
array('ID'=>87, 'PARENT_ID' => 2, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 2.1',),
array('ID'=>18, 'PARENT_ID' => 2, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 2.2',),
array('ID'=>19, 'PARENT_ID' => 3, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 3.1',),
array('ID'=>20, 'PARENT_ID' => 3, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 3.2',),
array('ID'=>21, 'PARENT_ID' => 4, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 4.1',),
array('ID'=>22, 'PARENT_ID' => 4, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 4.2',),
array('ID'=>23, 'PARENT_ID' => 87, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 2.1.1',),
array('ID'=>24, 'PARENT_ID' => 87, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 2.1.2',),
array('ID'=>25, 'PARENT_ID' => 23, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 2.1.1.1',),
array('ID'=>26, 'PARENT_ID' => 23, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 2.1.1.2',),
array('ID'=>27, 'PARENT_ID' => 19, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 3.1.1',),
array('ID'=>28, 'PARENT_ID' => 19, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 3.1.2',),
array('ID'=>1, 'PARENT_ID' => 20, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 3.2.1',),
array('ID'=>30, 'PARENT_ID' => 1, 'NAME'=> 'Пункт 3.2.1.1'));
?>
```

Comment: а не покажите образец маркированного списка, который вы хотите получить. я хоть узнаю, что это такое

Comment: https://html5book.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/dl.png

Comment: так с чем у вас проблема - с оформлением, с организацией данных. с кодировкой. какой код у вас получился, какие ошибки или что получилось? что так - что не так?

Comment: @splash58 речь очевидно идет о выводе многоуровневого списка, либо по крайней мере в соответствии порядку `id-parent_id`

Answer (score 0):

Сколько массивов столько и ключей начиная с нуля

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) { 
print_r($data[$i]['ID'].'<br>');
}

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 100
            [PARENT_ID] => 0
            [NAME] => Пункт 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [PARENT_ID] => 0
            [NAME] => Пункт 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [PARENT_ID] => 0
            [NAME] => Пункт 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 4
            [PARENT_ID] => 0
            [NAME] => Пункт 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 52
            [PARENT_ID] => 100
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 6
            [PARENT_ID] => 100
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 7
            [PARENT_ID] => 100
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.3
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 8
            [PARENT_ID] => 100
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.4
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 9
            [PARENT_ID] => 52
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.1.1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10
            [PARENT_ID] => 52
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.1.2
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 11
            [PARENT_ID] => 52
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.1.3
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 12
            [PARENT_ID] => 52
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.1.4
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 13
            [PARENT_ID] => 9
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.1.1.1
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 14
            [PARENT_ID] => 9
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.1.1.2
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 15
            [PARENT_ID] => 9
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.1.1.3
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 16
            [PARENT_ID] => 9
            [NAME] => Пункт 1.1.1.4
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 87
            [PARENT_ID] => 2
            [NAME] => Пункт 2.1
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 18
            [PARENT_ID] => 2
            [NAME] => Пункт 2.2
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 19
            [PARENT_ID] => 3
            [NAME] => Пункт 3.1
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 20
            [PARENT_ID] => 3
            [NAME] => Пункт 3.2
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 21
            [PARENT_ID] => 4
            [NAME] => Пункт 4.1
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 22
            [PARENT_ID] => 4
            [NAME] => Пункт 4.2
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 23
            [PARENT_ID] => 87
            [NAME] => Пункт 2.1.1
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 24
            [PARENT_ID] => 87
            [NAME] => Пункт 2.1.2
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 25
            [PARENT_ID] => 23
            [NAME] => Пункт 2.1.1.1
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 26
            [PARENT_ID] => 23
            [NAME] => Пункт 2.1.1.2
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 27
            [PARENT_ID] => 19
            [NAME] => Пункт 3.1.1
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 28
            [PARENT_ID] => 19
            [NAME] => Пункт 3.1.2
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [PARENT_ID] => 20
            [NAME] => Пункт 3.2.1
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 30
            [PARENT_ID] => 1
            [NAME] => Пункт 3.2.1.1
        )

)
```